# md5sum command on linux hangs for non existing file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am getting info of a file stored on remote server in my python code. I execute linux commands using remote access and get its output as string to parse and verify. My command finds a file on disk, gives it's latest timestamp and its md5sum. Problem is, if the file is not present, the md5sum command doesn't error out and keeps hanging causing my code exists without a proper traceback after a lot of time. File not present is a valid condition for my environment. How can I overcome this or add proper exception to the md5sum command.

```
stat -c '%Y %n' $(find / -iname abcd.txt); md5sum $(find / -iname abcd.txt)
```

Ideal output:

```
~# stat -c '%Y %n' $(find / -iname abcd.txt); md5sum $(find / -iname abcd.txt)
1457991261 /foo/bar/abcd.txt
4f13b0a40c285a86dcb64cf9edd14411 /foo/bar/abcd.txt
```

if abcd.txt is not present, stat errors out saying:

```
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
```

But md5sum keep on hanging.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `;` to connect the two commands. If the first fails, the second won't run.

Comment: Thanks @TomZynch ! That is a very easy and minimalistic solution for my problem!